# Passing 2 background images: 1 for mobile and 1 for desktop from PHP without having to repeat the HTML content?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Let's say we need to display 2 different images for mobile and desktop. We would usually do something like this:

HTML

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    background-image: url('image-for-mobile.jpg');
}
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
    .container {
        background-image: url('image-for-desktop.jpg');
    }
}
```

But what happens when we are getting those images from the server? Let's say from Wordpress or any other source?

One way to do it, would be:

HTML

```
<div class="container for-mobile" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $img_for_mobile; ?>);"></div>
<div class="container for-desktop" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $img_for_desktop; ?>);"></div>
```

CSS

```
.for-mobile {
    display: block;
}
.for-desktop {
    display: none;
}
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
    .for-mobile {
        display: none;
    }
    .for-desktop {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

For obvious reasons, even though this "works" this is not right because we are repeating the markup. What if we have a ton of content inside '.container'? We would have to repeat all that, only to have a different background image.

Another option would probably be passing the variables as data attributes and then with jQuery getting those variables and assigning the right background image in relation to the screen size. Something like this:

HTML

```
<div class="container" data-mobile="<?php echo $img_for_mobile; ?>" data-desktop="<?php echo $img_for_desktop; ?>"></div>
```

jQuery

```
// This is pseudo code, not tested
var imgForMobile = $('.container').data('mobile');
var imgForDesktop = $('.container').data('desktop');

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 1024) {
        $('.container').css('background-image', 'url(' + imgForMobile + ')');
    }
    else {
        $('.container').css('background-image', 'url(' + imgForDesktop + ')');
    }
});
```

How could we attack this situation in a more elegant and proper way? Any thoughts would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The correct way:**

This is what image `srcset` is for!

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

```
<img srcset="elva-fairy-320w.jpg 320w,
             elva-fairy-480w.jpg 480w,
             elva-fairy-800w.jpg 800w"
     sizes="(max-width: 320px) 280px,
            (max-width: 480px) 440px,
            800px"
     src="elva-fairy-800w.jpg" alt="Elva dressed as a fairy">
```

If I had to guess though, I think you would benefit from using this and `object-fit` together. Do you want the background image to be sized to `cover`?

If so, this is way the super responsive and efficient way to do this:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}
.container img {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}    

<div class="container">

    <img srcset="elva-fairy-320w.jpg 320w,
                 elva-fairy-480w.jpg 480w,
                 elva-fairy-800w.jpg 800w"
         sizes="(max-width: 320px) 280px,
                (max-width: 480px) 440px,
                800px"
         src="elva-fairy-800w.jpg" alt="Elva dressed as a fairy">        

</div>
```

**The older server side way:**

If you really wanted to do it in PHP like you have in the example, this is the pattern we use for things like this in WordPress.

```
$image = 'desktop.jpg';

switch (true) {
    case wp_is_mobile() :
        $image = 'mobile.jpg';
        break;
}

<div class="container" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $image; ?>);"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Drew! Even though I believe IE will cry with that object-fit, this approach is truly beautiful. Also, wp_is_mobile() checks the device but not the screen size, right? So if I see the website from a laptop and the browser happens to be shrinked, I guess it would still display the larger image. Right?

Comment: whoa dude, I did not know about object-fit, that's awesome. in the past I've resorted to using div background images instead of imgs just to use `background-size` but it looks I won't have to do that anymore. Excellent new piece of information!

Comment: @georgecodes yeah wp_is_mobile() is just a device check. But `srcset` only loads the correct size for the screen res, so that is the better solution.

Comment: @georgecodes I do want to point out, if you are using WordPress, then it sets `srcset` on most images automatically now. If you use `the_post_thumbnail()` and inspect the code, you will see it on the `img` tag. You might need to add a bunch of image sizes in `functions.php` if you need different resolutions available.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the CSS approach, by passing in a full URL or CDN.

If the rule inside of a media query that is `false`, that image won't be loaded by the browser.

```
.container {
    background-image: url('https://www.example.com/image-for-mobile.jpg');
}
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
    .container {
        background-image: url('https://www.example.com/image-for-desktop.jpg');
    }
}
```

There are alternatives which place this logic in either your HTML, JS, or even server code. HTML's answer is using a `srcset` attribute with an image, or using a `<picture>` element instead which was introduced in HTML5. `srcset` on an image is typically used to handle differences in pixel density, while the `<picture>` element is used to serve varying images using media queries. The first `<source>` whose media query matches the document is served, and you can include a general fallback, which allows backward compatibility for older browsers, however this approach loads at least 2 images - as the fallback will always be loaded.

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="big.jpg 1x, big-2x.jpg 2x, big-3x.jpg 3x" media="(min-width: 40em)" />
    <source srcset="med.jpg 1x, med-2x.jpg 2x, med-3x.jpg 3x" />
    <img src="fallback.jpg" alt="fancy pants" />
    <!-- fallback.jpg is *always* downloaded -->
</picture>
```

Comment: I did know know about the picture tag either. Awesome

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it in my site was I used JQuery to check if its a mobile browser (quick google will find the if statement used, its rather long)

Edit: 
Here: `if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 $('body').addClass('mobile');
}`

I made it append the body tags with class='mobile' 
and then in my CSS I have two sets:

```
body {
    background:black;
}
.mobile body {
    background: blue;
}
```